# Order numbers column by highest number, regardless of positive or negative

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe on synthetic scores and the difference between the two:

```
score_1    score_2    diff
10         15         5
7          9          2
13         23         10
12         4          -8
...
```

There are quite a few rows so I want to order the dataframe by the largest difference between score_1 and score_2. I'm currently using:

```
df.sort_values(by=['diff'], ascending=False)
```

But this returns:

```
score_1    score_2    diff
13         23         10
10         15         5
7          9          2
12         4          -8
```

Whereas what I'm looking for is:

```
score_1    score_2    diff
13         23         10
12         4          -8
10         15         5
7          9          2
```

For it to return the biggest difference in descending order regardless of whether it is a negative or positive difference

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by='diff', ascending=False, key=abs)
```

or, alternatively:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['diff'].abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index]
```

output:

```
   score_1  score_2  diff
2       13       23    10
3       12        4    -8
0       10       15     5
1        7        9     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `key` in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for absolute values:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['diff'], ascending=False, key=lambda x: x.abs())
print (df)
   score_1  score_2  diff
2       13       23    10
3       12        4    -8
0       10       15     5
1        7        9     2
```

Alternative solution with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and for descending order use negative positions:

```
df = df.iloc[(-df['diff'].abs()).argsort()]
print (df)
   score_1  score_2  diff
2       13       23    10
3       12        4    -8
0       10       15     5
1        7        9     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use lambda functions so you can use this in a transformer that can be pickled, you can use the `pandas.reindex()` function.

```
new_index = df['diff'].abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index
df.reindex(new_index)

   score_1  score_2  diff
2       13       23    10
3       12        4    -8
0       10       15     5
1        7        9     2
```

Comment: What is the link between lambda and a pipeline? You can use lambdas in a pipeline, or `sort_values`

Comment: Sorry, was multitasing. I meant to mention pickling a transformer. I have edited my response

Answer (score 0):

The two other answers are more pertinent but I give you another way with `rank`:

```
>>> df.iloc[df['diff'].abs().rank(method='dense', ascending=False).sub(1)]
   score_1  score_2  diff
2       13       23    10
3       12        4    -8
0       10       15     5
1        7        9     2
```